# Add HTML page to Wordpress keeping header and footer

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, static

Good morning, I'd like to add a HTML page containing a JS animation to my wordpress website but I also want to display wordpress header and footer in order to better "blend" it with the rest of the website, is it possible?

visually I'd like it to be like this:

WORDPRESS HEADER
HTML PAGE with JS ANIMATION
WORDPRESS FOOTER

I've tried simply adding the HTML code in a wordpress page content but I think the CSS of the HTML page is conflicting with the CSS of wordpress and it doesn't look good at all

Maybe I can simply add only the JS animation to a wordpress page? I'm not sure if it's possibile and how

any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Add a page with just page title. it will create a page with "page" prefix inside wp-content/themes/themename/page-test
you can write your own code there  or you can add short code to a page. it will display header and footer:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I can't find  "wp-content/themes/themename/page-test", any help? thanks

Comment: first you have to create a page from wordpress panel e.g page title: "test order" now go to wp-content/themes/themename/  create a php file name "page-test-order.php"  in that file use get_header(); for getting header and get_footer(); for getting footer

Comment: you can also see this example : https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/